# Déjà Dup backup to Ubuntu One fails with the error "backup location too small", but only 1.9 GB has been used in my backups on Ubuntu one

Tags: backup

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 using Déjà Dup backup to Ubuntu one with the free 5 GB storage, it has suddenly started failing with the error "backup location too small". But when I checked my backups on Ubuntu one, they only take 1.9 GB.  Apart from subscribing to extra storage, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You could delete all of the old backups except one of them. That way, they don't need to take up unnecessary space, but you still have one in case the next one fails.